# @Asynchronous doesn't work with more than one asynchronous methods in the same class

Tags: asynchronous, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm trying to use @Asynchronous to execute business. When I use:

```
ClassA {

  @Inject
  ClassB b; 

  public void runTest() {
     b.exec();
  }

}

@Named
@ConcurrencyManagement
@Startup
ClassB {
    @Asynchronous
    public void exec() {
    // codes here.
}
}
```

It works. But if ClassB changes to

```
@Named
@ConcurrencyManagement
@Startup
ClassB {
    @Asynchronous
    public void exec() {
    // codes here.
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void exec1() {
    // codes here.
    }
}
```

ClassA changes to

```
ClassA {

  @Inject
  ClassB b; 

  public void runTest() {
     b.exec();
     b.exec1();
  }

}
```

the exec() and exec1() are not running asynchronous. Does this mean ClassB can't contain more than one @Asynchronous methods?

I also move @Asynchronous to annotate ClassB, but it still doesn't work. What should I do to make exec() and exec1() runs asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem.

The first time. I set ClassB as:

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Startup
ClassB {
    @Asynchronous
    public void exec() {
    // codes here.
}
}
```

It works. But later I met another issue "javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException: WFLYEJB0241: EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on QueryInfo - could not obtain lock within 5000MILLISECONDS" so I change @Singleton to @ConcurrencyManagement. This @ConcurrencyManagement only works on stateless bean. So @Stateless needs to be add to ClassB.

```
@Named
@ConcurrencyManagement
@Stateless
@Startup
ClassB {
    @Asynchronous
    public void exec() {
    // codes here.
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void exec1() {
    // codes here.
    }
}
```

It works now.